# Raspberry Pi OpenVPN connects, but no internet access

Tags: pi-3b+

I am trying to make a VPN to my Raspberry Pi 3 B. I followed [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O560roc5Ia8) and installed OpenVPN in order to do it. I did the dynamic DNS thing and also port forwarded port 443 because I chose TCP since I want to use it at the library which blocks port 1191. I downloaded OpenVPN app on my phone and imported the config file. It connects the the VPN, but I cannot access the internet. I think ot worked at first until I rebooted. I did a similar tutorial on my Ubuntu server without the dynamic DNS and it works, but I want to do it on the Pi.
Here is my server conf file.

```
dev tun
proto tcp
port 443
ca /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/issued/raspberrypi_a20cf266-bf03-4542-85f7-8b08ac6b894$
key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/private/raspberrypi_a20cf266-bf03-4542-85f7-8b08ac6b894$
dh none
ecdh-curve prime256v1
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
# Set your primary domain name server address for clients
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.8.0.1"
# Prevent DNS leaks on Windows
push "block-outside-dns"
# Override the Client default gateway by using 0.0.0.0/1 and
# 128.0.0.0/1 rather than 0.0.0.0/0. This has the benefit of
# overriding but not wiping out the original default gateway.
push "redirect-gateway def1"
client-to-client
client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd
keepalive 15 120
remote-cert-tls client
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-crypt /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/ta.key
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
user openvpn
group openvpn
persist-key
persist-tun
crl-verify /etc/openvpn/crl.pem
status /var/log/openvpn-status.log 20
status-version 3
syslog
verb 3
#DuplicateCNs allow access control on a less-granular, per user basis.
#Remove # if you will manage access by user instead of device.
#duplicate-cn
# Generated for use by PiVPN.io
remote-cert-tls client
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-crypt /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/ta.key
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
user openvpn
group openvpn
persist-key
persist-tun
crl-verify /etc/openvpn/crl.pem
status /var/log/openvpn-status.log 20
status-version 3
syslog
verb 3
#DuplicateCNs allow access control on a less-granular, per user basis.
#Remove # if you will manage access by user instead of device.
#duplicate-cn
# Generated for use by PiVPN.io
```

On a different forum, this person suggested these two commands.

```
$ sudo /sbin/iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
$ sudo /sbin/iptables --table nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

It fixed it, but did not work after I rebooted the Pi again.

```
Create a file to hold the iptables rules. This example will use /etc/iptables.rules but other locations are fine too. The contents will be:

Code: Select all

*filter
:FORWARD ACCEPT
COMMIT

*nat
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT

Create another file /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/iptables with contents(change /etc/iptables.rules if your file is elsewhere):

Code: Select all

#!/bin/sh
/sbin/iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules

Make this file executable:

$ sudo chmod +x /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/iptables

and those two rules should apply each time the system boots.
```

I followed that, but it did not work. I then deleted the files I made then tried the original commands again, but they no longer fixed it. What can I do? Thank you.